# system.img approaching size limit

Tags: android, android-source

I built the current aosp project on `ubuntu16.04`, lunch `aosp_arm64-eng`.
When it finished, I got warning says:

> Created filesystem with 2639/163840 inodes and 268495/655360 blocks
>   WARNING: out/target/product/generic_arm64/system.img approaching size
>   limit (2684354560 now; limit 2684354560)

I wonder whether my the system.img is complete or not because only 2639/163840 inodes created, and why it is 2G large.

I know I can change `BOARD_SYSTEM_IMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE` to get the large `system.img`, but my phone space is limited to 2G, and there are zImage, `userdata.img`, and `ramdisk.img`.

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If system.img in out dir is created then everything has been done successfully.
To decrease memory usage you can do following things:

- Disable odexing (using `WITH_DEXPREOPT` and
  `DONT_DEXPREOPT_PREBUILTS` flag)
- Remove unnecessary locales from
  `PRODUCT_LOCALES`
- Optimize `PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG` flags
- Remove
  unnecessary packages from compilation